# Django: Clearing request.session between forms causes csrf token error?

Tags: python, django, session, token, csrf

I am facing a very specific problem that I've narrowed down to a particular reason, and I am afraid I may simply be misunderstanding or wrongly applying my logic here.

Django users will know that CSRF protection is handled by a django middleware and that each form used in the project should be followed by a {% csrf_token %} tag. My project contains an app that serves users data based on their OAuth2-authenticated sessions, for which I then save/retain some session-specific REST data.

As you can probably guess, I have to clear the session cache quite often in cases of new users, or some particular parameters changing in terms of the current user's session. In order to do this, I retain some of the values from the request.session dictionary and then clear the session like so

```
remember_dictionary = {
    '''some values that I wish to remember'''
}

request.session.clear()

for key, value in remember_dictionary.items():
    if value:
        request.session[key] = value
```

If this function has been called in the event of the user having two forms up on the website concurrently, the older form will throw a Forbidden Error/csrf token missing. I understand that the request.session.clear() probably has something to do with this, but I was under the impression that the csrf token would remain the same for the same request.session? As far as I am aware, request.session.flush() is what would be deleting request.session and creating a new one? Furthermore, I tried saving the csrf_token in request.session using the following line in my settings.py

```
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True
```

and then including the current csrf token value in my remember dictionary before I clear the session like so,

```
remember_dictionary = {
    '''some values that I wish to remember''',
    '_csrf_token': request.session.get('_csrf_token', False)
}

request.session.clear()

for key, value in remember_dictionary.items():
    if value:
        request.session[key] = value
```

I've verified that the csrf_token gets remembered in the second method, but submission of the older form will still throw Forbidden Error/csrf token missing.

Am I missing anything in particular in my workflow? Any help is appreciated, thanks.